# Jenkins pipeline multiline script command as variable

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

how can I save a command in a variable and executed anywhere in the stage

tried differnt way, but still success

here is my example

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
       myscript = sh '''
       echo "hello"
       echo "hello"
       echo "hello"
       '''
   }
   stages {
       stage("RUN") {
           steps {
               sh "${myscript}" 
           }          
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried remove `sh` from ` myscript = sh '''`,  you declare myscript to a string, thus should use `sh` to execute it.

Comment: look into command substitution in bash

Comment: make use of Jenkins shared library for this kind of expectation. Take a look at [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this. Not with a groovy variable but can be more dynamic with groovy function/method

```
def reusableScript(message) {
    sh """
      echo Hello World
      echo Hi ${message}
    """
}
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('01') {
            steps {
                script {
                    reusableScript("From ${env.STAGE_NAME}")
                }
            }
        }
        stage('02') {
            steps {
                script {
                    reusableScript("From ${env.STAGE_NAME}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```